# Restful API for parsing records

Tags: json, error-handling, api, go, rest

I'm trying to implement my own API. This code excerpt should show the basic working routines. The storage is temporary an in-memory-array and the only HTTP method for now is POST.

I outsourced the parsing into `ParseRecordRequest()`, because I use the code twice for POST and PUT requests and will extend it with further conditions.

All responses (errors and records) are generated by `GenerateJSON()`, which allows me to customize the response header etc. within a single place.

But what should I do, if `GenerateJSON()` can't marhsal the JSON? All usual errors are sent back with an `HandlerError` struct, that can't be marshalled in this case.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

type Record struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

var DB []Record
var latestID int = 0

type HandlerError struct {
    Code    int    `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func CreateRecord(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    payload, err := ParseRecordRequest(w, r)

    if err != nil {
        GenerateResponse(w, err)
        return
    }

    latestID++
    record := Record{latestID, payload.Name}
    DB = append(DB, record)
    GenerateResponse(w, record)
}

func ParseRecordRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*Record, *HandlerError) {
    data := new(Record)
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(data)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, &HandlerError{http.StatusInternalServerError, "Can't decode the JSON."}
    }

    if data.Name == "" {
        return nil, &HandlerError{http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid record name."}
    }

    return data, nil
}

func GenerateResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}) {
    payload, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "    ")

    if err != nil {
        // How should the error be handeled?
        // Sending an ErrorHandler is impossible,
        // because the Marshaler doesn't work
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    w.Header().Set("Accept", "application/json")
    w.Write(payload)
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.POST("/api/record", CreateRecord)

    fmt.Println("Server is running...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest running with `-race` to notice all the data races you have. Each HTTP handler is run in it's own goroutine and you can't just modify global variables from separate goroutines. (And, btw, there is [no such thing as a benign data race](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong).)

Comment: What do you mean with `-race`?

Comment: `go test -race`, `go build -race`, `go run -race`, etc. See the help for those.

Comment: I'll take a further look for the use of this command while I extend this little prototype.